# Error while connecting MongoDB ATLAS TO MONGO DB COMPASS

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

I am a beginer in mongoDB and learning Mongodb atlas.

- In MongoDB Atlas, Under **database access** created username and password ( password is system generated and has no special character)
- Under **Network access** added a public ip address (allow access from anywhere)
- Under **database deployment** loaded sample database.
- Now I wanted to see my cluster data, so wanted to connect it to vs code or MongoDB Compass. I clicked **connect**, selected connect using mongo db compass, copied the string.
- now i opened Mongodb compass, and under New connection i.e **connect to a MongoDB deployment**, i entered my URL

  mongodb+srv://gourav_singh:7gamf8UkL8B6MET@cluster0.9dmds.mongodb.net/test
- clicked **Connect**
  But i got error as : **Unable to connect: connect ECONNREFUSED 3.6.85.199:27017**

How I can fix it, Looking for kind help. Thanks in advance